# Error in creating Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have a problem in creating maven project in eclipse.
Following Error occurs:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

```
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <groupId>tests1</groupId> 
    <artifactId>test1</artifactId> 
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <name>test2</name> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6</version> 
    </dependency> 
</project>
```

Comment: Could you provide pom.xml, please?

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>tests1</groupId>
  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>test2</name>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
</project>

Comment: You'd better update the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write it in your pom.xml , try it ... 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exactly the same issue after setting up my windows. I deleted the local repository folder & it worked. Try deleting the folder in the path like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2\repository
```

Comment: I tried deleting it but  I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your pom.xml is wrong. Use this link https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies. Put dependency inside  tag.

If it still doesn't solve your problem could you also make sure that you have this dependency in your repository by navigating to it on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Give right path for settings.xml
Windows --> Preference --> Maven --> User Settings